# Select com when e case

Tags: mysql, postgresql, query, select

Tenho a seguinte consulta select:

```
select
F.nu_ine INE,
to_char(D.dt_ficha, 'YYYYMM') as CMP,
I.co_cbo_2002 CBO,
CASE 
WHEN (B.tp_atend = 1 or B.tp_atend = 2 or B.tp_atend = 5) and I.co_cbo_2002 != '225142' THEN '0301010030'
WHEN (B.tp_atend = 1 or B.tp_atend = 2 or B.tp_atend = 5) and I.co_cbo_2002 = '225142' THEN '0301010064'
WHEN B.tp_atend = 4 THEN '0301040079'
WHEN B.tp_atend = 6 THEN '0301060037'
ELSE B.tp_atend
END PROCEDIMENTO,
DATE_PART('year', D.dt_ficha) - DATE_PART('year', B.dt_nascimento) IDADE,
H.no_pessoa_fisica,
F.no_equipe,
I.no_cbo,
M.no_proced
from
tb_cds_atend_individual B,
tb_cds_ficha_atend_individual D,
tb_equipe F,
tb_cds_prof G,
tb_pessoa_fisica H,
tb_cbo I,
tb_proced M
where F.nu_ine = G.nu_ine
and G.nu_cns = H.nu_cns
and D.co_cds_prof = G.co_seq_cds_prof
and G.nu_cbo_2002 = I.co_cbo_2002
and B.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = D.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl
and D.dt_ficha >= '2017-10-01' and D.dt_ficha <= '2017-10-30'
and M.co_proced = PROCEDIMENTO <<<<<ESSA LINHA
order by B.tp_atend
```

Preciso fazer uma comparação da coluna `M.co_proced` como resultado do `case` (0301040079, 0301060037, etc), porém recebo um erro dizendo que a coluna `PROCEDIMENTO` não existe (pois é um "apelido que dei a ela").

Como faço pra corrigir isso?

**o banco é postgre, porém marquei mysql pois muitos códigos são semelhantes**

Comment: dá uma olhada no comando `with`. Coloca esse teu código no `with` e depois filtra ele na sequência.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O alias da coluna não vai funcionar no where, você tem que colocar a expressão também na sintaxe.

```
select
F.nu_ine INE,
to_char(D.dt_ficha, 'YYYYMM') as CMP,
I.co_cbo_2002 CBO,
(CASE 
WHEN (B.tp_atend = 1 or B.tp_atend = 2 or B.tp_atend = 5) and I.co_cbo_2002 != '225142' THEN '0301010030'
WHEN (B.tp_atend = 1 or B.tp_atend = 2 or B.tp_atend = 5) and I.co_cbo_2002 = '225142' THEN '0301010064'
WHEN B.tp_atend = 4 THEN '0301040079'
WHEN B.tp_atend = 6 THEN '0301060037'
ELSE B.tp_atend
END) PROCEDIMENTO,
DATE_PART('year', D.dt_ficha) - DATE_PART('year', B.dt_nascimento) IDADE,
H.no_pessoa_fisica,
F.no_equipe,
I.no_cbo,
M.no_proced
from
tb_cds_atend_individual B,
tb_cds_ficha_atend_individual D,
tb_equipe F,
tb_cds_prof G,
tb_pessoa_fisica H,
tb_cbo I,
tb_proced M
where F.nu_ine = G.nu_ine
and G.nu_cns = H.nu_cns
and D.co_cds_prof = G.co_seq_cds_prof
and G.nu_cbo_2002 = I.co_cbo_2002
and B.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = D.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl
and D.dt_ficha >= '2017-10-01' and D.dt_ficha <= '2017-10-30'
and M.co_proced = (CASE 
WHEN (B.tp_atend = 1 or B.tp_atend = 2 or B.tp_atend = 5) and I.co_cbo_2002 != '225142' THEN '0301010030'
WHEN (B.tp_atend = 1 or B.tp_atend = 2 or B.tp_atend = 5) and I.co_cbo_2002 = '225142' THEN '0301010064'
WHEN B.tp_atend = 4 THEN '0301040079'
WHEN B.tp_atend = 6 THEN '0301060037'
ELSE B.tp_atend
END)
order by B.tp_atend
```

Comment: funcionou em parte, o código '0301040079' está sendo lido como bigint e o da outra tabela como string. como faço pra converter o resultado do case em string?

Comment: use cast pra converter `cast(CASE 
WHEN (B.tp_atend = 1 or B.tp_atend = 2 or B.tp_atend = 5) and I.co_cbo_2002 != '225142' THEN '0301010030'
WHEN (B.tp_atend = 1 or B.tp_atend = 2 or B.tp_atend = 5) and I.co_cbo_2002 = '225142' THEN '0301010064'
WHEN B.tp_atend = 4 THEN '0301040079'
WHEN B.tp_atend = 6 THEN '0301060037'
ELSE B.tp_atend
END as varchar) PROCEDIMENTO,` mesmo assim, ele tira o primeiro zero. alguma dica?

Comment: fiz assim:
`(CASE 
WHEN (B.tp_atend = 1 or B.tp_atend = 2 or B.tp_atend = 5) and I.co_cbo_2002 != '225142' THEN '0301010030'
WHEN (B.tp_atend = 1 or B.tp_atend = 2 or B.tp_atend = 5) and I.co_cbo_2002 = '225142' THEN '0301010064'
WHEN B.tp_atend = 4 THEN '0301040079'
WHEN B.tp_atend = 6 THEN '0301060037'
ELSE B.tp_atend
END)::varchar PROCEDIMENTO,` mesmo assim não deu

Comment: tem que fazer na coluna que está bigint tipo `(CASE WHEN (B.tp_atend = 1 or B.tp_atend = 2 or B.tp_atend = 5) and I.co_cbo_2002 != '225142' THEN '0301010030' WHEN (B.tp_atend = 1 or B.tp_atend = 2 or B.tp_atend = 5) and I.co_cbo_2002 = '225142' THEN '0301010064' WHEN B.tp_atend = 4 THEN '0301040079' WHEN B.tp_atend = 6 THEN '0301060037' ELSE B.tp_atend::varchar END)`